# Office 365 Service Communications API not working

Tags: office365

I have been using PowerShell to query the Office 365 Service Communications API for service health. This has been working well for me for several months.  Starting about a week ago the script began intermittently returning no data.  There is no error just no data returned.  A few days ago the issue started to get worse and the script now only returns data occasionally. The API I am using is described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn776043.aspx
with example code here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/cammurray/archive/2014/09/24/using-powershell-to-obtain-the-office365-dashboard.aspx
My question is: Is there something wrong with the API? I have not changed anything on my end, and the script does return data sometimes.  Is anyone else having this same problem?
I realize that there is a new version of the API, but the documentation says it is still in preview, and nothing I can find says that the existing API has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into this myself today, across several different tenants.  The URI in the link above was working, but would only return information-type events (preferredEventType = 2), not incidents or maintenance events (0 and 1).

Then, I noticed that the SCOM management pack for Office 365 uses a different URI (https://office365servicehealthcommunications.cloudapp.net/shdtenantcommunications.svc/GetEvents).  I changed my PowerShell script to use this instead, and it's working.

Comment: Yes I saw the same behavior with the event types. I actually use 2 different scripts with the same uri, one for service alerts (0) and one for message center notifications (2).  The Message center script never stopped working.  Odd thing is as of about 4 am this morning the uri I was using is working.  It has returned data consistently the past 50 times.  But now I don't know if I can trust it.  I will try your suggestion, maybe it will be more consistent.